# Reading to a text file that does not have the text extension ".txt"

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file in Python 3.8 that is has the extension ".input". However, it is meant to be read as a text file. I tried to connect to the file using this code:

```
file = open('file.input', 'r')
print("The contents of the file are:",file)
```

However, it does not output the contents of "file.input" (I wrote "Hello World" in there as a sample message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `read` (or one of the other read methods) on the object returned by `open`.

```
with open('file.input', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

The `with` keyword is helpful for making sure the file you open gets closed. For more information on file I/O in python you should really read the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files.

Comment: I used a with statement, and then I appended the data from the file into a list. However, the list still returns as empty.

Comment: That seems like a different question altogether. If you want to read the contents of a text file, this will definitely work. To test this you can write something manually in a file and try it out. If you need more help, feel free to ask another question but please read the link I included in my answer first.